API Binance API-key invalid
Hi I've been trying to make a connection to the Binance API. However, I present this error
{"code":-2014,"msg":"API-key format invalid."}

I don't know why. I'm using the hashmac as a signature. I assure that the data is passed correctly. This is the code
API_KEY = ''
SECRET_KEY = ''

BASE_URL = "https://api.binance.com"

def get_historical_data_link(symbol, data_type, start_time, end_time):

    endpoint = "/sapi/v1/futures/histDataLink"
    url = BASE_URL + endpoint

    timestamp = int(time.time() * 1000)

    params = {
        "symbol": symbol,
        "dataType": data_type,
        "startTime": start_time,
        "endTime": end_time,
        "timestamp": timestamp
    }

    query_string = '?'.join([f"{key}={value}" for key, value in params.items()])

    signature = hmac.new(SECRET_KEY.encode('utf-8'), query_string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    # signature = hashlib.sha256(SECRET_KEY.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    print(signature)
    params["signature"] = signature

    headers = {
        "X-MBX-APIKEY": API_KEY
    }

    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
        response.raise_for_status()  
        return response.json()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return None

symbol = "BTCUSDT"
data_type = "T_DEPTH"  
start_time = 1730419200039
end_time = 1730419400039    
data = get_historical_data_link(symbol, data_type, start_time, end_time)
data

Thanks in advance :)
